# Does the Apple IIgs FPI assert /CROMSEL for *write* accesses to the extended ROM space?

Tags: apple-ii, apple, apple-iigs

The FPI (fast processor interface) ASIC in the Apple IIgs generates the /CROMSEL chip-select signal, which is used to select a ROM in the memory expansion slot. Obviously the /CROMSEL signal must be asserted for read accesses to the extended ROM space, but what about write accesses? If the 65816 performs a write to the extended rom space in banks F0-FD (F0-FB for ROM 3 systems), does the FPI assert /CROMSEL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, for writes to the extended ROM space, the IIgs ROM 01 FPI memory controller does not assert /CROMSEL. I assume it’s the same for the newer CYA memory controller chip in ROM 03 systems but I have not tested.

Here are the logic analyzer traces. First is a read from F0/0000, in which /CROMSEL is asserted as expected:
[image: ROM 01 IIgs extended ROM read]

Next is a write to the same address, in which /CROMSEL remains unasserted during phi2:
[image: ROM 01 IIgs extended ROM write]

Interestingly, there is a 32ns period after the write to F0/0000 is over in which /CROMSEL becomes active, before going back to deselected before the end of /phi2. This suggests that in the FPI, /CROMSEL is implemented as an asynchronous disjunction of /WE and a registered address.

Answer (score -1):

> If the 65816 performs a write to the extended rom space in banks F0-FD (F0-FB for ROM 3 systems), does the FPI assert /CROMSEL?

Yes, it does. CROMSEL is a select signal, and as such only dependant on the address, not any other signal (like direction).

---

The reason of providing CROMSEL is to make extended ROM selection easy and safe by avoiding the chance that ROM (card) developers only decode for Fx, creating a potential address collision for banks FE and FF.

Comment: "Select signal" does not necessarily mean that the /R, /W or R//W signals are not used to calculate the signal. There are also a lot of examples where a write to some address and a read from the same address access totally different devices.

Comment: @MartinRosenau And that's related how? Even with the special case soft switches (which  I guess you want to refer to), you need to differentiate between an address driven select signal, and a function selection by direction. Beside that, mind to explain why you think this invalidates my answer?

Comment: *And that's related how?* It's only because you wrote: "... is a select signal, and **as such** only dependent on the address ...". I just looked on the Acorn A3000 schematic: The ROM (sharing the address space with the MMU) /CS signal must be dependent on the direction (read) because the W//R signal is not connected to the ROMs... So there are examples of /CS signals being dependent on the W//R signal.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge, @Raffzahn, but I am looking for a citation or at least some anecdotal story about it, not just speculation. Thanks for explaining select signals, but MartinRosenau is right, and his example is spot-on. Often it is a good idea to not select a ROM when writing so that its /OE pin can be tied low without concern for bus contention. Eventually I will capture a trace with my logic analyzer showing what happens.

Comment: @MartinRosenau I see, you're viewing it from the receiving chip perspective. A valid PoV, but rather unusual when designing a system as select (not chip select) design is viewed from the generation side. Especially on the Apple II, where Woz played a lot with 'em :)

Comment: @ZaneKaminski What makes you think it's a speculation? Given, I haven't done a new card for the IIgs for some years :))

Comment: Sorry if I was being presumptuous, @Raffzahn. Anyway I have tested and confirmed that indeed nCROMSEL is deasserted when nWE is asserted, so nCROMSEL does depend on nWE. I will capture a trace with my logic analyzer tomorrow and post it.